# C# & Unity Simple coding issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am going through the Unity tutorials and right now my character can move left and right. But now I am trying to make it move forwards & backwards, which I did, but I am having trouble making it so it's only possible within a certain boundary. Comparing it to my left to right code I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm sure it's simple for someone who knows better.

Appreciate the help guys. The zRangeBackwards is set to 10. (float, 10f) Left and Right works perfect, forwards and backwards works but not within the boundary I am trying to set here.

Appreciate any help.

`

```
  // Move left to right within the XRange boundary
        if(transform.position.x < -xRange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-xRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        if (transform.position.x > xRange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(xRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        //Move forwards and backwards within zRangeBackwards boundary
        
        if (transform.position.z < -zRangeBackwards)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-zRangeBackwards, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
       
        if (transform.position.z > zRangeBackwards)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(zRangeBackwards, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
```

`

I tried comparing it to my left to right code but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please avoid generic question titles like this. You should be as specific as possible when creating questions otherwise you end up wasting people's time as they are forced to open your question to know what you mean.

Comment: Btw https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is you try to limit the X axis again for the forward/backward directions, but you should limit the Z axis, like this:

```
    //Move forwards and backwards within zRangeBackwards boundary
    
    if (transform.position.z < -zRangeBackwards)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -zRangeBackwards);
    }
   
    if (transform.position.z > zRangeBackwards)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, zRangeBackwards);
    }
```

Comment: Ohhhh I see how it's structured now. You're completely correct. Thank you!